# The interpretation of the general reference

Tags: grammar, definite-article, zero-article

Often when we use the zero article article, we talk generally. When we use "the" - we talk about something specific. I asked the similar questions but now some ideas struck my mind and I wish to clarify the matter.

1) *"I like music on my player"* - can it mean that I like any music I upload on my player because that music is good?

2) *"I like **the** music on my player"* - **only** that music, that is on my player at **the moment of speaking**, or it can also mean that I like any music I upload there (a changing set)?

The idea of a changing set is not very clear to me. Can "the + noun (pl)" be a changing set?

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: *I like music on my player* means you like *music* rather than, say, *videos* on my player. *The music on my player* can mean the same thing, you like the music rather than the videos on your player, or you like the music on your player; in both cases *the music* refers to the music currently on your player.

Comment: I like the music on my player, can also mean I like the music on my player, but not the music that is not on my player.

Comment: CarSmack, thanks. You say - "but not the music that is not on my player" - does it mean that there are no exceptions from this? If to say it out of a blue, can it mean that I like the music on my player slightly more than music somewhere else, and even though there can be places where I like music to the same extent or less than on my player?

Comment: *I like the music on my player* refers to the specific music that is on your Player at the moment of speaking. You can compare or contrast that specific music to anything you want. *The music on my player* has nothing to do with any other music, unless you make a connection. So, yes, you can say I like the music on my player slightly more, or equal to, the/some music that is somewhere else.

Comment: *The music on my Player* is short for *The music that is on my player*, so it refers only to that music on your player at the time you say it. This is because of *is* (whether spoken or not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I like  **(no article)** music on my player.

Does not refer to *the specific music* on your player, but simply that you like to listen to *some kind of music* - as opposed to audio books, for example.

> I like **the** music on my player.

Means the music currently on the player.

If you want to talk about a changing set of titles (some currently on your player, some not), I can't think of a direct way to say so in one sentence.

Comment: Stephie, thanks. Please look at another example: "I like the music I upload on my player" - is it true, that as we have not a state (for instance: to have) but an action verb here (upload), the set is changeable, so I am not talking about the songs I upload now, but about any I upload at any time?

Comment: Present tense **I upload** means you upload on a regular basis, so that meaning of the verb is still there in *the music I upload on(to) my player.* It does not have to be the same music, and you upload music on a regular basis or "at any time". By contrast, *I like the music **I am uploading** on(to) my player* refers to that music you are currently in the process of uploading.

Comment: When I am uploading music, it is specific music, and since 'music' is a non-count noun, the only way to mean specific music is *the*, so you have to say 'I like *the* music I am uploading on my player* And uploading means right now.